# Returning custom item in JQueryUI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to return the "No Record Found" message as ListItem when there is no record.  I managed to detect whether the result is empty or not by using "data.d".  However, I don't know how to return "No Record Found" as the data item.  Could you please help me with this?  Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "/WebServices/Misc.asmx/GetOtherQualifications",
                    data: "{ 'ModuleID': '" + $("#<%= hdModuleRef.ClientID %>").val() + "', 'search': '" + $("#<%= txtCourseName.ClientID %>").val() + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data.d == "") {

                                return {
                                    value: "No record found",
                                    id: -1
                                }                            

                        }
                        else {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    value: item.Name,
                                    id: item.KeyID
                                }
                            }))
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
return {
    value: "No record found",
    id: -1
};
```

You need to call the `response` function, which notifies the widget of results:

```
response([{
    value: "No record found",
    Id: -1
}]);
```